# How to capture dataEvents for a date column in jqgrid

Tags: datepicker, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

Hi I have a jqgrid grid where I am doing the below .Can someone help me with DataEvent type that should help capturing the date change ?

```
                   {
                    name: "MonthYear",
                    index: "MonthYear",
                    width: 70,
                    align: "center",
                    sorttype: "date",
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (e) {
                            Utility.customDatePicker(e);
                        },
                        dataEvents: [
                          {
                              **type: "changeDate",**
                              fn: function (e) {
                                  // -- need to do some calculation on basis of Date change
                              }
                          }]
                    },
                    formatter: "date",
                    formatoptions: { srcformat: "M/Y", newformat: "M/Y" },
                },
```

I did the above but I am unable to capture the dateChange event as I need to do some calculations on the basis on Date captured on change.Thanks

Comment: You should use `type: "change"`. Additional problem could be the implementation of `Utility.customDatePicker`, which you use in `dataInit`. If you use jQuery UI Datepicker then you should use `onSelect` parameter of the datepicker where you trigger `"change"` event explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oleg but my requirement is such that I am using a custom date-picker which retrieves just the Month and Year and I was using dataEvents,type as "change" only still no luck.

Comment: Sorry, but if you want that somebody helps you then you should provide details what you do. The information "custom date-picker" gives absolute no information. Your "custom date-picker" should trigger "change" event or any other "custom event". You can use the name of the event at the value of `type` property. Triggering of the standard "change" event seems to me the mostly natural way.